# Mandar Dato de un Activity a un Fragment que está dentro de un Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-intent

Estoy intentando pasar un dato de un Edittext de un Activity hacia un Fragment que se encuentra contenido en un Navigation Drawer.

Aquí mando en dato al Fragment

```
Intent get = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentNuevas.class);
get.putExtra("email", email.getText().toString());
```

Aquí recupero el dato en el Fragment

```
Intent get = getActivity().getIntent();
final String usu = get.getStringExtra("usu");
```

La intención es recuperar el dato para usarlo en una URL y que ésta quede de la siguiente manera:

```
URL = new URL("http://xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/consulta.php?id="+dato);
```

para así poder hacer un filtro dinámico en la consulta

Comment: @Elenasys... si puedes me ayudas... no consigo leer el dato...

Comment: El fragment esta relacionado a la Activity por lo tanto puedes obtener su referencia y obtener su valor, revisa mi respuesta ye comentas.

Answer (score 2):

si esta en el Activity puedes obtener si referencia de esta forma:

```
EditText edt = (EditText) getActivity.findViewById(R.id.edittext);

String valorEdiText = edt.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma es usando SharedPreferences: almacenas en string ese EditText, dentro de cualquier Activity de la App:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("e_mail", email.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Y lo obtienes en cualquier fragment, dentro de onCreateView, de esta forma:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Preferences", 0);
String correo_e = prefs.getString("e_mail", "");
tuTextView.setText(correo_e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar info a un fragmento, llamas a *setArguments* cuando lo creas, despues en el método *onCreate* o *onCreateView* de tu fragmento puedes recuperarlo:

Al crearlo guardamos los valores:

```
MiFragmento miFrag= new MiFragmento();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("email", email.getText().toString());
miFrag.setArguments(args);
```

Para recuperarlo lo hacemos así:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
String email = args.getString("email", "mailNulo"); //mailNulo sería el valor por defecto en caso de que args no contenga una variable llamada email.
```

Comment: con `f` te refieres a `miFrag` en el primer trozo de código?

Comment: Si, perdona, se me ha ido, editado.